# Alternative to cut function in R for data.tables - integer variables to factors

Tags: r, data.table, cut

I want to convert the integer variable `hp` to a categorical variable, cut by 10.

```
mtcars[, hp_cat := cut(hp, 
    breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, Inf), 
include.lowest = TRUE )]
```

This yields the desired result, however it is query tedious to write out all the numbers. Is there an faster way? Also ideally the alternative would result in nicer factor names too.

Attention: I would like to have the result in data.table... so NO dplyr.

Comment: `cut(hp, breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 160, by = 10))` ?

Comment: is it possible to say have a category where everything over 160 goes into?

Comment: Yes, use Inf at the end, see what I did below

Comment: would it be possible to change the limits of the function seq from for example (0,10] to [0,10) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the sequence function.  Depending what the situation is you may a `-Inf` as the first element in the vector.  Also the label parameter will allow you to assign names, this works in the code below: `labels = paste0("Group",2:length(BRKS))`

```
BRKS <-    c( seq( 0 , 160, 10 ) , Inf )

mtcars[, hp_cat := cut(hp, breaks = BRKS , include.lowest = TRUE )]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which should be faster:

```
mtcars[, hp_cat2 := ceiling(hp/10)*10][hp_cat2 > 160, hp_cat2 := Inf]
```

Using the right limit as the naming for your *nicer factor names*